# attempt to invoke method crash(updated) encountered new error

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, invoke

hi currently i encountered this problem

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.sp.ez_mart_z, PID: 31934
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
                  at com.sp.ez_mart_z.StorelayoutFragment.onCreateView(StorelayoutFragment.java:41)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2087)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1113)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1295)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1682)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:541)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Application terminated.

i cant seem to figure out how to solve this heres my code. this code is suppose to display an imageview after pressing on on the options in the app drawer

```
public class StorelayoutFragment extends Fragment {
ImageView mImageView;
PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;

public StorelayoutFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_store_layout, container, false);


    // Any implementation of ImageView can be used!
    mImageView = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    // Set the Drawable displayed
    Drawable bitmap = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.small_layout);
    mImageView.setImageDrawable(bitmap);

    // Attach a PhotoViewAttacher, which takes care of all of the zooming functionality.
    // (not needed unless you are going to change the drawable later)
    mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(mImageView);
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: oh yes my mistake . what a silly mistake i make

Answer (score 0):

Need to return `inflate` layout from `onCreateView` and use same View instance for accessing View's from it. do following changes in `onCreateView`:

```
View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_store_layout, container, false);
 mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

.....

return view;
```

Comment: oh yes my mistake i just realise i made a silly mistake

Comment: updated my code and encountered another problem this time due to  mImageView.setImageDrawable(bitmap);